# gcc "relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_M24A'" error when linking statically against ffmpeg on linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ffmpeg, linker

I am trying to build a JNI shared library which statically links to ffmpeg.

But at the linking stage, gcc fails with the following error:

`` /usr/bin/ld: ./lib_lin64/libswscale.a(swscale.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_M24A' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC ``

I am using the following commands to compile my jni library:

`gcc -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux -I ./include -fPIC -c *.c`
`gcc -shared -Wl,--no-undefined -o libnv_avc_dec.so *.o -Wl,-Bstatic -L./lib_lin64 -lavcodec -lavutil -lswresample -lswscale -Wl,-Bdynamic -lm`

And I only use h264 decoding feature, so I am also building ffmpeg from source with the minimal required feature set. The ./configure command I use is:

`./configure \
--enable-pic --prefix=ffmpeg-dist \
--disable-debug --enable-version3 --enable-gpl \
--disable-everything --enable-hwaccel=h264_vdpau --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi --enable-hwaccel=h264_qsv --enable-hwaccel=h264_mmal \
--enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=h264_vdpau --enable-decoder=h264_crystalhd --enable-decoder=h264_mmal --enable-decoder=h264_qsv \
--disable-iconv --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-zlib --disable-lzma  --disable-bzlib  --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avformat --disable-avfilter --disable-postproc`

So, as I understand, the linker tells me that ffmpeg should be compiled with -fPIC flag in order to make a shared library. But I believe that I've already done so by specifying the --enable-pic configure flag. And I am pretty much stuck here because I am not very familiar with autotools, nor with ffmpeg build process in particular.

If this is the issue of ffmpeg .a libs not being compiled with -fPIC flag, how can i force it? And if this is not the case, what am i doing wrong and how can i fix this error?

Environment details: Ubuntu 14.04.3 64-bit in Virtualbox, gcc 4.8.5 and 5.3 (both give the same results), ffmpeg v.2.8.5

Comment: Hm, why do you try to link .a-libraries to your shared library? This is usually not possible. Does it work with `-Bdynamic`? The needed libraries must be present in shared object form (*.so) then, of course

Comment: Dynamic linking worked. However, I'm curious because I've managed to do this with osx libraries. Why would it not be possible on linux?

Comment: For some reason they are probably relocatable in contrast to the linux .a-libs

Comment: If the static libraries were built with -fPIC, my experience is that GCC is able to link them statically into .so.  However, I'm confronted with the same problem on Debian-based systems (it works on Fedora/OpenSUSE.  Weird).

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a shared library but need to link with static ffmpeg libs add linker flags:

```
-Wl,-Bsymbolic
```

When using cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-Bsymbolic")
```